# @Async annotation is creating threads, but only one thread is taking all the load

Tags: asynchronous, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to persist huge payload to database. So I decided to use asynchronous call to persist a batch of records. I enabled Asynchronous processing by using @EnableAsync annotation. I also used @Async on a method on my service layer as below

```
@Async
@Transactional
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> insertRecords(List<Record> records) {

    recordRepository.saveAll(records);
    recordRepository.flush();
    LOGGER.debug(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" -> inserting);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Boolean.TRUE);
}

Above method is called from another service method
@Transactional
public void performSomeDB(InputStream is){

     //perform another CRUD operation
    processStream(is);
}

private void processStream(InputStream is){

     //Read stream using JsonReader and load into a list
     // record by record. Once the desired batch is met, pass the 
     // list to insertRecords
    List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();        
    List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> statuses = new ArrayList<>();
    while(stream has data){
         records.add(record);
         statuses.add(insertRecords(records);
    }

    System.out.println(statuses.size()); // It returns >1 based on the iterations.
```

Some of the code added above is more symbolic, than actual code.

When I looked into logs, I see that statuses.size() are returning value >1, which means more threads are spawned. But only one thread is used to persist and that is running in sequence for each iteration.

```
http-nio-9090-exec-10 -> insert records
http-nio-9090-exec-10 -> insert records.
......................................
```

In logs, I see only one thread is running and persisting a batch of records in sequential order.

Why only one thread is taking the load to persist all records.

Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: It seems the bottleneck in your application is the database. If that is true, hitting it with more requests in parallel probably won't help. Especially when all the requests hit the same table and indexes this will just create lock contention.

Answer (score 1):

As for  @Async annotation , self-invocation – calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work.
You should make the method in a separate class and reference it using the bean object of this class.

```
@Component
public class DbInserter {
@Async
@Transactional
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> insertRecords(List<Record> records) {

    recordRepository.saveAll(records);
    recordRepository.flush();
    LOGGER.debug(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" -> inserting);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Boolean.TRUE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the magic and general idea of Async. It's sharing the full load without generating several threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring's Java-configuration, your config class needs to implements AsyncConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
      @Override
        public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
            executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
            executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
            executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyPool");
            executor.initialize();
            return executor;
        }
    }
```

You can refer below document for more details : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html